# Requirejs in Magento 2 gives me undefined instead of my library

Tags: requirejs, magento2, babylonjs

I'm using Requirejs in Magento 2 to load Babylonjs (version 3.3). But in my callback, requirejs gives me an undefined in my BABYLON object.

I have tried doing it with a requirejs-config.js to substitute names, but no luck.

```
require(['My_Module/js/babylon','My_Module/js/babylon.gui.min'], function(BABYLON, GUI) {
    console.log(BABYLON); // undefined
    new BABYLON.Color3(0,0,0,0) // TypeError BABYLON.Color3 is not a constructor
});
```

The files I am trying to load are in `My/Module/view/frontend/web/js`. and are named `babylon.js` and `babylon.gui.min.js`

I expected my BABYLON variable in my callback to be the BABYLON object as I would import it in a CommonJS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the library defined itself as `babylonjs`. not as `My_Module/js/babylonjs`.